# How to set Dejavu as default font for all applications in my lxde?

Tags: lubuntu, fonts, lxde

My desktop is lxde.
I want to set Dejavu as default font for all applications.
preferences--desktop preferences
To select Dejavu as default font .
[image]

Now reboot.
1.panel font are not
[image]
2. fonts in input bar are not Dejavu
[image]

How to set Dejavu as default font for all applications in my lxde?

Answer (score 1):

To input `lxappearnce` in console,to select font from the poping window.